"Flutter Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory" but shows correct path in terminal - macos
I'm working on a Flutter project on macOS, and when I try to run the app on an Android emulator, I get the following error:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: 
“/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openlogic-openjdk- 
17.jdk/Contents/Home“

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

However, when I check JAVA_HOME from my terminal, it points to the correct path:
/Users/rashmi/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.1/Contents/Home

How do I fix this issue so Flutter uses the correct JAVA_HOME?
Additional Information
When I run /usr/libexec/java_home -v in the terminal, it gives the following output:
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
17.0.1 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 17.0.1" 
/Users/rashmi/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk- 
17.0.1/Contents/Home
1.8.321.07 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" 
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
/Users/rashmi/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk- 
17.0.1/Contents/Home


Finally I figured Out the solution Myself and Here’s How I Fixed It:

Open the terminal and navigate to your home directory(cd ~).

Run open .config in terminal and then config directory will open.

Go to flutter -> settings inside .config directory.

Inside the settings file, there will be a field that looks like this
:


{
 "jdk-dir": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home"
 }


Replace this path with your correct JDK path.

Save the settings file and close it.

Now, run your Flutter project again



what do you mean by home directory?
